# Merging PDF files with PDFTK

Tags: windows, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have a directory with PDF files that looks like this:

```
2016_AAA_SomeRandomText1.pdf
2016_BBB_SomeRandomText1.pdf
2016_AAA_SomeRandomText2.pdf
2016_BBB_SomeRandomText2.pdf
2016_AAA_SomeRandomText3.pdf
2016_BBB_SomeRandomText3.pdf
...
```

Note: SomeRandomText3.pdf changes but it is in pairs.

So, I want to go through the folder via Windows CLI with a FOR loop and generate a PDF file for each pair of SomeRandomText with PDFTK. So, the output will be like this:

```
2016_AAA_SomeRandomText1.pdf + 2016_BBB_SomeRandomText1.pdf = 2016_SomeRandomText1.pdf
2016_AAA_SomeRandomText2.pdf + 2016_BBB_SomeRandomText2.pdf = 2016_SomeRandomText2.pdf
2016_AAA_SomeRandomText3.pdf + 2016_BBB_SomeRandomText3.pdf = 2016_SomeRandomText3.pdf
...
```

Here is what I have so far (assuming I am working in `C:\user\pdfs`):

```
FOR /R %I IN (*.pdf) DO pdftk
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, tested:

replace `"%~dp0"` to your "actual" path to `"C:\user\pdfs"`

```
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f tokens^=1-3^delims^=_ %%i in ('^^^< nul where ".:*.pdf"')do if not exist "%%~i_%%~nk%%~xk" (
     "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "%%~i_*_*%%~nk%%~xk" cat output "%%~i_%%~nk%%~xk"
    )
```

---

The results form this `for` loop  and `if` condition is similar:

```
if not exist "2016_SomeRandomText1.pdf" ( 
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "F:\2020-SU\Q1058228\2016_*_SomeRandomText1.pdf" cat output "F:\2020-SU\Q1058228\2016_SomeRandomText1.pdf"
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I’ll tell you how I did it in bash, and maybe you can translate it.

I use `pdfunite` (a little more direct than `pdftk`) but once you figure out the syntax, it’s easy enough.

```
for AFILE in `ls 2016*AAA*.pdf`
## For each of the files starting with 2016_AAA
do
   BFILE=`echo $AFILE | sed -e 's/AAA/BBB/'`
## I use stream editor to replace the AAA with BBB and define the
## new file name.  You can probably use SUBSTITUTE in Win
   pdftk $AFILE $BFILE cat output OUTPUT-$AFILE
## This will combine $AFILE and BFILE into OUTPUT-AFILE
done
```

Hopefully this will give you a start.